# .NET button in div with style="display:none" not firing

Tags: c#, .net, css

I have a pretty simple web-form set up in .Net where I am leveraging jQuery for some of the functionality.  I am using the DOMWindow portion for part of the presentation layer.

There is a login form in a div that is set to display:none.  When a user clicks a button on the page, it displays the login form.  However the .Net button for the login form will not fire it's event when display is set to none.  If i take this out, it fires fine.  I have also tried using the visibility attribute, but no luck.

the div code is:

`<div id="Login" style="display:none;">`

The launching code is:

`click <a href="javascript:LaunchLoginWindow();" style="color:#000000;">here</a> to login.<br />`

the jQuery code is:

```
function LaunchLoginWindow() {
    $(document).append("#Login");
    $.openDOMWindow({
        loader: 1,
        loaderImagePath: 'animationProcessing.gif',
        loaderHeight: 7,
        loaderWidth: 8,
        windowSourceID: '#Login'
    });
}
```

Any help or explanation that anyone can offer is appreciated.

I noticed i had some code in there defining a client-side function on the Login div.  I removed this so as to eliminate it as a possible issue.

Answer (score 2):

I can see in your code that you are appending the div #Login but not setting its style property back to normal like block so. Set it back to block and i am sure it will work

try adding somthing like:

```
$(document).append("#Login").show();
```

Comment: thanks, Shekhar.  The issue was different, but the help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after playing around with this using firebug, I found the issue:  When the jQuery plug-in DOMWindow creates its display layer, it appends to the HTML node of the DOM, which places the control outside the asp.net form tag.  Therefore the button and actions associated with it via the DOMWindow are not recognized by .Net.  So i edited the DOMWindow source file to append to the DOM form node rather then the html node.

The drawback is that the source has now been customized and will have to be QA'd thoroughly, especially if any further changes are made.  But I hope to manage this effectively via commenting in the file.

Hope this helps anyone else who hits this issue.

pbr